# Laravel 10, Relacion Muchos a Muchos, no muestra fecha guardada en tabla Pivot

Tags: mariadb, pivot, modelorelacional, laravel-10, php81

tengo 2 tablas relacionadas “Muchos a Muchos”,

[image]

nota: El campo atendido me da la fecha de atencion, por lo cual depende de la relacion MxM , y creo que no puede ir en alguna de las tablas base de la relacion.

La situación que tengo es cuando , quiero presentar todas la prestaciones de un paciente, me muestra toda la info relacionadas a las tablas base de la relación , pero no me muestra el valor del campo atendido , a pesar que tiene guardado bien los datos.

[image]

Como se puede ver me muestra la columna atendido (fecha) con la fecha de hoy . No con la que tiene guardada.

[image]

[image]

Uso Laravel 10, livewire 3,  php 8.2 ,  mariaDB 10

que puede estar pasando, muchas gracias !!!!!.

Comment: Saludos, ninguna imagen que agregaste es visible, [edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/607925/edit) para poder corregir este problema, ahora bien si lo que quieres mostrar es codigo o mensajes de error por favor copia y pega éstos mismos en formato de texto en lugar de agregar capturas. ;)

Comment: Hola Gracias por contestar , ya edite el la pregunta. Gracias.

Comment: Tal como te han dicho, y a pesar de que ya has encontrado respuesta a tu pregunta, muestra el código y los mensajes de error _como texto, con formato_. [No todos pueden ver las imágenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976).

Answer (score 0):

les cuento como solucione el problema:

En el controlador, cambie la consulta :

```
 $this->paciente = Paciente::find($id);
```

por esta:

```
 $this->paciente = Paciente::find($id)->prestaciones;
```

o tambien puede ser de esta manera

```
$this->paciente = Paciente::with('prestaciones')->find($id);
```

En la vista view.blade.php

```
 @if (!empty($paciente))
   @foreach ($paciente as $item)
      <tr class="bg-white border-b border-blue-500">
           <td class="py-2 px-4">{{date('d-m-Y',strtotime($item->pivot->atendido))}}</td>
                        <td class="py-2 px-4">{{ $item->nombre }}</td>
                      </tr>
                    @endforeach
                  @else
                      <tr class="bg-white border-b border-blue-500">
                          <td class="py-2 px-4" colspan="2">No hay resultados !!!</td>
                      </tr>
                  @endif
```

En este codigo , como el campo atendido esta en la tabla pivot "paciente_prestacion", estoy obligado a hacer la referencia a la tabla pivot

```
$item->pivot->atendido
```

Mientras que el nombre de la prestacion lo saco de la relacion , entonces va asi:

```
 $item->nombre
```

Recordemos que $item , esta direccionando a :

```
$item = $Paciente->prestaciones
```

ESpero que le sirva a alguien mas, asi queda la presentacion

[image]

Todavia no hice un orden por fecha :) muchas gracias.